# Dell poweredge 1650 server blinking orange

Tags: dell, dell-poweredge

I have an old server running for my application. I just checked that it has started flashing orange suddenly from blue. Does anyone know what does this mean?

Comment: I assume you are talking about one of HDD lights?

Comment: What O/S do you have running on the system?

Comment: Craig- OS is Linux

Answer (score 12):

Install the [Dell Openmanage](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/software/svradmin/) Server administrator and see what it tells you. Last time I installed this, I don't believe it required a restart, which is good if you possibly have failing drives.

Since I assumed you were running Windows, [HERE](http://www.dell.com/downloads/global/power/ps2q07-20070309-Senthil-OE.pdf) is the link for the Linux documentation for OpenManage

Answer (score 3):

According to the [Dell PowerEdge 1650 Systems Installation and Troubleshooting Guide](http://support.dell.com/support/edocs/systems/pe1650/en/it/8g550c20.htm#1050603) it means there's a problem. It's most likely a harddrive related problem, so I suggest you check the HDD lights (link goes to HDD part of the guide).

Comment: If it is hard drive problem, can I check from terminal if there is any issue with hard drive ?

Comment: I suggest you check the other answer. While I'm not familiar with Openmanage, I'm willing to bet that it has the utilities needed to diagnose the issue or find the problematic harddrive.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a Windows machine yes just install Dell OpenManage, open the webportal and browse to System->Storage->Virtual Disks and it will show you the status of all virtual disks.  If it turns out its not the hard drive browse to Systems -> Logs and it will describe why the alert is on.

You can do the same on a unix machine, or there are live versions of open manage you can install on a CD and boot to and read the Dell hardware logs via that.